# How can I create a boolean mask by summing row-wise (SQL Alchemy)?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given:

- a number
- a SQL Alchemy table (`<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Table'>`)
- and a list (that can vary in length) of SQL Alchemy columns (`<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.ColumnClause'>`)

I need to build a boolean mask that is `True` on the records where the row-wise sum of the columns is equal to the number.

Example:

- number = 6
- column_list = [sa.column(col_1), sa.column(col_2), sa.column(col_3)]
- table:

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 | 8 |
| 6 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Returns: [True, False, True]

**Caveat**: The computation must be performed prior to executing the query (e.g. in the `where` clause, `case` statement, etc), not after performing fetchall or similar.

I'm not even sure where to start. I know I can select the columns:

`sa.select(column_list).select_from(table)`

Also, a case statement will probably be needed:

`sa.case([(ROW_WISE_SUM == number, True)], else=False)`

Edit: I think I'm getting closer but I still can't figure out how to handle the list of column clauses:

`sa.case((sa.func.sum(column_list) == number, True), else_=False)`

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'ColumnClause'
```

.

.

.

```
[SQL: CASE WHEN (sum(%(sum_1)s) = %(sum_2)s) THEN %(param_1)s ELSE %(param_2)s END]
[parameters: {'sum_1': [<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.ColumnClause at 0x7fe62bf075d0; col_1>, <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.ColumnClause at 0x7fe62bf6e090; col_2>, <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.ColumnClause at 0x7fe62b0fabd0; col_3>], 'sum_2': 6, 'param_1': True, 'param_2': False}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use a subquery:

```py
# create test table
tbl = sa.Table(
    "so68720845",
    sa.MetaData(),
    sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False),
    sa.Column("col_1", sa.Integer),
    sa.Column("col_2", sa.Integer),
    sa.Column("col_3", sa.Integer),
    sa.Column("col_4", sa.Integer),
)
tbl.drop(engine, checkfirst=True)
tbl.create(engine)

# insert test data
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(
        tbl.insert(),
        [
            {"id": 1, "col_1": 1, "col_2": 2, "col_3": 3, "col_4": 3},
            {"id": 2, "col_1": 2, "col_2": 0, "col_3": 2, "col_4": 8},
            {"id": 3, "col_1": 6, "col_2": 0, "col_3": 0, "col_4": 1},
        ],
    )

# do the test
target_value = 6
col_list = [tbl.c.col_1, tbl.c.col_2, tbl.c.col_3]
col_sum = sum(col_list)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    subq = sa.select(tbl.c.id, col_sum.label("col_sum")).subquery()
    results = conn.execute(
        sa.select(subq.c.id, sa.case((subq.c.col_sum == 6, 1), else_=0))
    ).fetchall()
    print(results)  # [(1, 1), (2, 0), (3, 1)]
```